# Fabric CrashLog only show the crashed .so file, doesn't show the detail line number

Tags: google-fabric

I have a native crash in my app,and the crash uploads,but it shows only the crashed .so file, don't have the detail crash line, just missing word in every line.[image].

and when the crash happens,the studio can log the detail messages,like this.[image]

my question is why Crashlytics don't show the detail crash log like AndroidStudio.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The most likely issue is that symbols are not being uploaded correctly. A few things to check, make sure that you're Gradle Crashlytics blocks looks like: crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
  manifestPath 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}
and that you're running ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease to upload your symbols.

Comment: Thanks for answer it. The two steps you mentioned I do have done. The difference is that my flavour is Alpha and buildType is debug,so I running ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsAlphaDebug, does it work? And I wanna to know what task crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease is doing, how it upload the symbol, and what is symbol ?

Comment: @MikeBonnell it could be great if you give us an android studio project configured with Crashlyitics NDK

Comment: @gxela It would be following the Gradle steps here: https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk

Comment: @MikeBonnell That is exactly what I did, but I am not building my shared lib with gradle, it is copied under src/main/jniLibs/<arch>/, so I defined that path within the crashlytics {} bloc. The crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease took more than a minute to finish. Is there a way to check the symbols uploaded to crashytics ? The line numbers are missing and it's hard to know why...

Comment: @MikeBonnell my project doesn't contains any so file, but contains aar library, and aar contains so files, and if so crash in the aar, I only run crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease can work?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

I have added this code into the `build.gradle` and it will get all the symbols from `.so` and I can found the crash report into firebase

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    //https://medium.com/@aungkyawmyint_26195/setting-up-ndk-crashlytics-android-11ad775676f7
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511783/crashlytics-android-ndk-missing-all-symbols-in-crash-reports
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('assemble')) {
        task.finalizedBy "crashlyticsUploadSymbols" + task.name.substring('assemble'.length())
    }
}
```

no need to do anything else

no need to fire this `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbols{variant}` command every time